# How do I call a class component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have two react classes where one is in a file called app.js while the other is in inputs.js . i want to call PersonList class into the App class, and this is my code:

```
inputs.js file

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: '',
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ id: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${this.state.id}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Person ID:
            <input type="text" name="id" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import PersonList from './inputs.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res=>{
        const persons =res.data;
        this.setState({persons});
      })
  }
  render(){

    return(
      <ul>
        {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <PersonList />
    );
  }
}
```

i'm trying to call it using `<PersonList />` but im getting this error

```
./src/App.js
  Line 26:7:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

  24 |         {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
  25 |       </ul>
> 26 |       <PersonList />
     |       ^
  27 |     );
  28 |   }
  29 | }
```

please assist

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is you are trying to return multiple elements in your `return` statement.

You just need to wrap with a **React Fragment** as the following:

```
render() {
    return <>
      <ul>
        {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <PersonList />
    </>
}
```

Read further about [**Fragment**](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) in the link, also see from the documentation:

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return multiple component.

You have to use a special component called `Fragment` in order to return only one component. This "Fragment" component will not appear in the DOM.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import PersonList from './inputs.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res=>{
        const persons =res.data;
        this.setState({persons});
      })
  }
  render(){

    return(
     <React.Fragment>
       <ul>
        {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
       </ul>
       <PersonList />
     </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Render return can not return more than one element - you can modify the code by wrapping it inside any html element or using React fragment or using blank tags -

//1. Wrap inside any html tag - like - div - but this will add an extra dom node -
<div>
   <ul>
     {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
   </ul>
   <PersonList />
</div>

//2. Wrap inside react fragment which will not add an extra dom node -  
<React.Fragment>
   <ul>
     {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
   </ul>
   <PersonList />
</React.Fragment>

//3. use blank tags - but this way you can not pass some "key" attribute - 
<>
   <ul>
     {this.state.persons.map(person =><li>{person.name}</li>)}
   </ul>
   <PersonList />
</>
```